# Show that if $l$ is a cluster point of $\{ x_n \}$, then there is a sub-sequence that converges to $l$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

I've seen the standard $\frac{1}{N}$ proof of this in other stack exchange comments, but wondering if this is a valid proof as well. I'm unsure of my construction of $n_k$ even though I tried to make it monotone increasing as best as possible. I'm also new to analysis in general, so any pointers on style are appreciated too.

Proof: Suppose that $l$ is a cluster point of $\{ x_n \}$. That is, given any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists n \geq N$ such that $|x_n - l| < \epsilon$. Define $n_k$ recursively as follows:

$n_1 = \inf(\{ n: |x_n - l| < \epsilon \} )$

$n_k = \inf(\{ n: n \geq n_{k-1}+1 \land |x_n - l| < \epsilon \})$

Every $n_k$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers, so by the well-ordering principle there exists an infimum. Each $n_k$ satisfies $|x_{n_k} - l| < \epsilon$, it's simple to check that it satisfies the definition of a limit that converges to $l$.

Comment: You have constructed a subsequence whose distance to $l$ is less than $\epsilon$ for that specific $\epsilon$, thus it is not necessary that the sequence converges to $l$. For example, for each $\epsilon$ you may end up with a different subsequence.

Comment: If I'm getting this right then, I need to come up with a subsequence that does not depend on the choice of $\epsilon$ that converges to $l$?

Comment: Here is a way to construct the desired subsequence. Suppose that $x_{n_k}$ has been chosen so that $|x_{n_k}-l|<1/k$. Choose $|x_{n_{k+1}}-l|<1/(k+1)$ and $n_{k+1}>n_k$. Per the hypothesis, it is clear that this is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your construction.

(1) Whenever you choose an $\epsilon$, you do construct a subsequence and guarantee them to stay within the distance $|x_{n_k}-l|<\epsilon$. However, this **cannot** guarantee them to converge to $l$, because they could oscillate around $l$, rather than converge to it. "Converge to $l$" means "being closer and closer" to $l$. But here your $\epsilon$ is some fixed value, so it gives those points some space to oscillate around $l$, rather than being closer and closer to $l$. You may argue, my $\epsilon$ is not fixed, but arbitrarily small, which leads to the second issue.

(2) Whenever you modify your $\epsilon$ to be a smaller value, you have to reconstruct your subsequence, because your previously selected subsequence may not satisfy your new $\epsilon$. For example, you first set $\epsilon=1$, and construct a subsequence $x_{n_{k_1}}$. Next, when you set $\epsilon=\frac12$, those points in your subsequence $x_{n_{k_1}}$ may not satisfy $|x_{n_{k_1}}-l|<\frac12$, hence you have to re-select points and reconstruct a new subsequence $x_{n_{k_2}}$. Note that, before we say a (sub)sequence to be convergent or not, we first have to fix this (sub)sequence.

Finally, regarding your comment:

> If I'm getting this right then, I need to come up with a subsequence that does not depend on the choice of $ϵ$ that converges to $l$?

A (sub)sequence is convergent or divergent doesn't and shouldn't depend on what $ϵ$ you choose. The $ϵ$-notation/language is just a way to describe it, which shouldn't affect this (sub)sequence is convergent or not, since converge/diverge is the intrinsic property of the (sub)sequence.